# Linq create an array of Dto objects, with an array in it

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, linq, nhibernate

I have a rich NHibernate dbo object that I need to query to extract a keyword and related array of country codes.

To explain:
I have 3 related DBO objects returned from a database, that have the following structure:

```
class DboCountry{
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
    public string CountryCode {get;set;}
}       

class DboPage{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Keyword {get;set;}
}

class DboPageCountry{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public DboThemePage DboThemePage {get;set;}
    public DboCountry DboCountry {get;set;}
}
```

As such when querying the database I get a List of DboPageCountries that contain multiple repeating DboPage.Keyword that are associated to various DboCountry.CountryCode

What I need to do is take the List of DboPageCountries and create an array of DtoKeywordCountryCode with the following structure:

```
class DtoKeywordCountryCode{
    public string Keyword {get; set;}
    public string[] CountryCodes {get; set;}
}
```

So far, using Linq, I've either been able to group the keywords, but not get the associated country codes, or get keywords and country codes, but not associated as a unique Keyword against an array of applicable CountryCodes.

Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
var items = new List<DboPageCountry>(); //list of DboPageCountries

var items2 = from x in items.GroupBy(x => x.DboThemePage) 
             select new DtoKeywordCountryCode { Keyword = x.First().DboThemePage.Keyword, CountryCodes = x.Select(c => c.DboCountry.CountryCode).ToArray() };
```

Comment: Great, I also found the mixed query option below

Answer (score 0):

```
DtoThemePage[] dtoThemePageArrayFull = (from tpc in dboThemePageCountryList group tpc by tpc.DboThemePage.Keyword into k
                                        select new DtoThemePage
                                        {
                                            Keyword = k.Key,
                                            CountryCodes = k.Select(c => c.DboCountry.CountryCode).ToArray<string>()
                                        }).ToArray<DtoThemePage>();
```